# Typescript basic loop for display

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop

```
sum(list: number[]): number { 
  console.log(list); 

  let sum = 0; 
  for (let i of list) { 
    sum = sum + i; 
    console.log('element i =' + i); 
  } 
  console.log('sum after sum = ' + sum); 
  return sum; 
}
```

It is a really simple function but somehow, it does not do what expected. I call this method on a specific list. When I display my list I got 8 elements display as supposed. The issue is when i want to display each action on the for loop, I only display the first one. First of all i thought it was a declaration place issue but after a while i cant find the real reason nothing is working.

Basically my output is :

```
0: 0 
1: 0 
2: 0 
3: 0 
4: 0 
5: 0 
6: 1 
7: 1 
element i =0 
sum after sum = 0
```

I should obviously get the display of each element and the sum has to be : 2.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you create the array that you pass in as `list`? When I run this with `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]` I get the expected results (`sum = 2`).

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to my code right now. I ll have to wait until next Monday :(

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using, and how are you executing it. I copied your code into a Quokka instance in WebStorm running Typescript 3.2.4 and got the same result as p.s.w.g. I did add the word function before sum, but that was the only change I made other than setting up a call of sum([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1]);

Comment: @Sox- please, help the answerers reproduce your issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: Thanks for answering me, I feel so dumb to ask for help on a function like that. As I told PSWG I wont be able to access anything until Monday. I will answer ASAP. Thanks again !

Comment: Basically, when my colleague creates the corresponding list he uses the method .push with 0 or 1.
I also use Webstorm but my version of typescript is 2.9.2 but for code this simple I dont think the version has something to do with this \

Comment: I still cannot reproduce it by using `.push`. As smnbbrv said, please provide a MCVE. If we can't reproduce the same behavior you're seeing, we're just guessing.